# Can't use Component method in controller

Tags: cakephp, plugins, cakephp-2.0, cakedc

I am trying to use the Cake DC utils plugin (http://github.com/CakeDC/utils) so I can use the Archive to create a blog structure similar to Wordpress, but when I call the method I get an sql syntax error:

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'archiveLinks' at line 1
```

I am not sure how I am supposed to properly access the method, I have the plugin loading in my Bootstrap file.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Using plugins is a two step process in most cases, especially when using Components, Behaviours and Helpers.

Firstly, and correctly you need to load the plugin in your `app/Config/bootstrap.php` using `CakePlugin::load('MyPlugin')` but then you also actually need to use the file in your relevant class.

Components & Helpers

```
// app/Controller/ExamplesController.php
public $components = ['MyPlugin.Component'];

public $helpers = ['MyPlugin.Helper'];
```

Behaviours

```
// app/Model/Example.php
public $actsAs = ['MyPlugin.Behavior'];
```

So in short, the problem is that your component isn't loaded in the controller, hence why the framework is trying to pass your `archiveLinks` as SQL.